# recording 'bursts' of samples at 300 samples per sec

Tags: matlab

I am recording voltage changes over a small circuit- this records mouse feeding. When the mouse is eating, the circuit voltage changes, I convert that into ones and zeroes, all is well.

BUT- I want to calculate the number and duration of 'bursts' of feeding- that is, instances of circuit closing that occur within 250 ms (75 samples) of one another. If the gap between closings is larger than 250ms I want to count it as a new 'burst'

I guess I am looking for help in asking matlab to compare the sample number of each 1 in the digital file with the sample number of the next 1 down- if the difference is more than 75, call the first 1 the end of one bout and the second one the start of another bout, classifying the difference as a gap, but if it is NOT, keep the sample number of the first 1 and compare it against the next and next and next until there is a 75-sample difference

I can compare each 1 to the next 1 down:

```
n=1; m=2;
for i = 1:length(bouts4)-1

if bouts4(i+1) - bouts4(i) >= 75 %250 msec gap at a sample rate of 300
boutend4(n) = bouts4(i);
boutstart4(m)= bouts4(i+1);
m = m+1;
n = n+1;
end
```

I don't really want to iterate through i for both variables though...

any ideas??

-DB

Answer (score 1):

That's actually not too bad.  We can actually make this completely vectorized.  First, let's start with two signals:

1. A version of your voltages untouched
2. A version of your voltages that is shifted in time by 1 step (i.e. it starts at time index = 2).

Now the basic algorithm is really:

1. Go through each element and see if the difference is above a threshold (in your case 75).
2. Enumerate the locations of each one in separate arrays

Now onto the code!

```
%// Make those signals
bout4a = bouts4(1:end-1);
bout4b = bouts4(2:end);

%// Ensure column vectors - you'll see why soon
bout4a = bout4a(:);
bout4b = bout4b(:);

% // Step #1
loc = find(bouts4b - bouts4a >= 75);
% // Step #2
boutend4 = [bouts4(loc); 0];
boutstart4 = [0; bouts4(loc + 1)];
```

## Aside:

Thanks to tail.b.lo, you can also use `diff`.  It basically performs that difference operation with the copying of those vectors like I did before.  `diff` basically works the same way.  However, I decided not to use it so you can see how exactly your code that you wrote translates over in a vectorized way.  Only way to learn, right?

## Back to it!

Let's step through this slowly.  The first two lines of code make those signals I was talking about.  An original one (up to `length(bouts) - 1`) and another one that is the same length but shifted over by one time index.  Next, we use `find` to find those time slots where the time index was `>= 75`.  After, we use these locations to access the `bouts` array.  The ending array accesses the original array while the starting array accesses the same locations but moved over by one time index.

The reason why we need to make these two signals column vector is the way I am appending information to the starting vector.  I am not sure whether your data comes in rows or columns, so to make this completely independent of orientation, I'm going to make sure that your data is in columns.  This is because if I try to append a `0`, if I do it to a row vector I have to use a space to denote that I'm going to the next column.  If I do it for a column vector, I have to use a semi-colon to go to the next row.  To completely avoid checking to see whether it's a row or column vector, I'm going to make sure that it's a column vector no matter what.

By looking at your code `m=2`.  This means that when you start writing into this array, the first location is `0`.  As such, I've artificially placed a `0` at the beginning of this array and followed that up with the rest of the values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! That was very helpful! One more issue- why am I getting durations of zero sometimes?? Surely this should not happen? Thanks so much

Comment: @user2312820: You're very welcome. When you say "durations" of zeroes, do you mean the difference between successive voltages can be zero sometimes?  If that's the case, then that makes sense because during a certain collection of samples, the voltage applied may not have changed and so the difference between successive readings will inevitably zero. Can you clarify?

Comment: I subtract boutstart from boutend and the bout appears to be 0 samples in length- if this is the case, why is it counted? I am not looking at the voltages themselves, but the sample times at which they were collected. If a bout starts at 255, how can it also end at 255??   I can (and have) excluded durations under 10ms in length (3 samples) but Still dont quite understand the zeroes

Comment: @user2312820: You will probably need to add an extra zero at the end of your `boutend` array as we didn't calculate a value for the end.  As such, simply append a 0 to it by doing: `[bouts4(loc); 0];`.  As for the zeroes, this might be attributed to the fact that we forgot to include a `0` at the end.  Try doing this and see if your data lines up.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

```
time_diff = diff(bouts4);
new_feeding = time_diff > 75;
boutend4 = bouts4(new_feeding);
boutstart4 = [0; bouts4(find(new_feeding) + 1)];
```